# Doing a NotifyDataSetInvalidated() in a Dialog don't work outside of listfragment

Tags: android, android-listview, ormlite, listadapter

I have inserted a record using dialog. However when I do a listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), nothing happened. Any tips on how to do this? I loaded records from my database then using adapter to load record on the list view.

**The Dialog is part of an Activity that extend FragmentActivity** Im not sure if this will help.

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(ItemListActivityMain.this)
                    .setTitle("Update Status")
                    .setMessage("Please Enter Plate Number")
                    .setView(input)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Editable value = input.getText();


                            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Insert Main Car details" + value,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                            DatabaseManager.init(getApplication());

                            RoadMainTableFile roadMainTableFile = new RoadMainTableFile();

                            roadMainTableFile.setPlate_Number(value.toString());

                            DatabaseManager.getInstance().addOrUpdateRoadMainTableFile(roadMainTableFile);


                            final List<RoadMainTableFile> allRoadMainTableFilesList = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getAllRoadMainTableFilesList();

                            List<String> plateNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (RoadMainTableFile wl : allRoadMainTableFilesList) {
                                plateNumber.add(wl.getPlate_Number());
                            }


                            listadapter = new PlateNumberAdapterMain(ItemListActivityMain.this,
                                    R.layout.snippet_list_row_main, plateNumber);


                             **Nothing happened and no error encountered.**
                            listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                        }

                    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            }).show();
```

My List Adapter:

```
    package com.xxxx.roadexpensereport.Main;

/**
 * Created by Exponencially Rich on 6/05/2014.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.toksis.roadexpensereport.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;



public class PlateNumberAdapterMain extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private List<String> plateNumber = null;
    private Context context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;
    private ArrayList<String> arraylist;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public PlateNumberAdapterMain(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> plateNumber) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId, plateNumber);

        this.context = context;
        this.plateNumber = plateNumber;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(plateNumber.size()> 0) {

            this.arraylist.addAll(plateNumber);
        }
        packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != plateNumber) ? plateNumber.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != plateNumber) ? plateNumber.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;


        // This is needed so that your list view will not load forever when there is no record.
        if(rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row_main, parent, false);
        }



        String data = plateNumber.get(position);
        if (null != data) {

            TextView plateNumber = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.plateNumber);


            plateNumber.setText(data);



        }
        return rowView;
    }


   // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        plateNumber.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            plateNumber.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            //*if (wp.                              .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))*//*
            for (String wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    plateNumber.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**My ListFragment**

```
   public class ItemListFragmentFirstPage extends ListFragment {

    /**
     * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
     * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

    /**
     * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
     * clicks.
     */
    private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

    /**
     * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
     */
    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

    /**
     * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
     * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
     * selections.
     */
    public interface Callbacks {
        /**
         * Callback for when an item has been selected.
         */
        public void onItemSelected(String id, String action);
    }

    /**
     * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
     * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
     */
    private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(String id, String action) {
        }
    };

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ItemListFragmentFirstPage() {
    }

    private List<String> plateNumber;
    private int position = 0;
    public PlateNumberAdapterMain listadaptor = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //Load records to listview.
        new LoadRecords().execute();


    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

         registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
        if (savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
            setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.

        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }

        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
        mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
        // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.

        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(Integer.toString(position), " ");
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    }



    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
            outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
        }
   }

    /**
     * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
     * given the 'activated' state when touched.
     */
    public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
        // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
        // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick
                ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
    }

    private void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
        if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
            getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
        } else {
            getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
        }

        mActivatedPosition = position;
    }


    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d("ReminderListFragment", "onContextItemSelected called");
        }



        switch(item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.menu_delete:

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Delete Main Record",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
            case R.id.menu_record_travel:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Travel Reports",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                /*Pass Parameter to the second page. Use the Plate number*/
               /* Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragmentSecondPage.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);*/

                mCallbacks.onItemSelected("0", "Travel");

                return true;

            case R.id.menu_edit:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Edit MAin Record",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_generate_report:
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mCallbacks.onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id, "report");

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Generate Report",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);


    }



    /*Long press on the item list*/

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo
            menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


        MenuInflater mi = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu_item_longpress, menu);


    }


    private class LoadRecords extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            DatabaseManager.init(getActivity());

            //Load records.
            final List<RoadMainTableFile> allRoadMainTableFilesList = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getAllRoadMainTableFilesList();

            plateNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (RoadMainTableFile wl : allRoadMainTableFilesList) {
                plateNumber.add(wl.getPlate_Number());
            }


            listadaptor = new PlateNumberAdapterMain(getActivity(),
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row_main, plateNumber);
/*
 */
/*Sort The list. This has a slow speed*//*

            Collections.sort(applist, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));

*/

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null,
                    "Loading List...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //plateNumber.clear();

        new LoadRecords().execute();
        /*plateNumber = Dat.getItems(); //reload the items from database*/
       // listadaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: and where did you used this `listadapter`?

Comment: I added the list adapter. The list adapter is already used to load previous records. When I add a record using menu, I used the dialog.

Comment: I suggest that you use a `CursorAdapter` instead of an `ArrayAdapter`. It will take care of updating your `ListView` for you.

Comment: do you mean that for auto load of listview the best design is the Cursor Adapter?

Comment: Im not sure though is it works in a dialog but might wort the reading.

Comment: But let us first fix this one?

Comment: Or maybe instead of doing a change notification, I will reload the listfragment?